# Installing files into sd card without button

Tags: android, mp3

Currently, I have a button which the users have to press in order to get the .mp3 from raw into the sdcard. I tried putting the void in my onCreate void, but it gives me an error. How can I change the code so that it can work on onCreate? LogCat error:

Here is the code im using for the button:

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/music/Zen1.mp3");
            if (myFile.exists()) {
                meditateScreen();
            } else {
            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
            String name1 = "Zen1";
            String name2 = "Zen2";
            String name3 = "Zen3";
            String name4 = "ZenPing";
            File file1 = new File(path, name1 + ".mp3");
            InputStream is1 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.s1);
            File file2 = new File(path, name2 + ".mp3");
            InputStream is2 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.s2);
            File file3 = new File(path, name3 + ".mp3");
            InputStream is3 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.s3);
            File file4 = new File(path, name4 + ".mp3");
            InputStream is4 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ping);

            try {

                OutputStream os1 = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                byte[] data1 = new byte [is1.available()];
                is1.read(data1);
                os1.write(data1);
                is1.close();
                os1.close();
                //
                OutputStream os2 = new FileOutputStream(file2);
                byte[] data2 = new byte [is2.available()];
                is2.read(data2);
                os2.write(data2);
                is2.close();
                os2.close();
                //
                OutputStream os3 = new FileOutputStream(file3);
                byte[] data3 = new byte [is3.available()];
                is3.read(data3);
                os3.write(data3);
                is3.close();
                os3.close();
                //
                OutputStream os4 = new FileOutputStream(file4);
                byte[] data4 = new byte [is4.available()];
                is4.read(data4);
                os4.write(data4);
                is4.close();
                os4.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            meditateScreen();
            }
```

Here is the XML:

```
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.malthorn.zenstatemeditation/com.malthorn.zenstatemeditation.MeditateScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at com.malthorn.zenstatemeditation.MeditateScreen.<init>(MeditateScreen.java:36)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
02-01 00:30:34.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: use [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) to push files into eclipse.. ;)

Comment: I did that already for my emulator, but im trying to make it so that the files install on startup if they havnt already for people on their phones @crazydevloper